# проблема с расположением картинки

Tags: html, css

```
    <h2><a href="pic.html">Pictures</a></h2>
    <ol>
    <li><div  class="pic"><img src="start_ files\img1.jpg" high="325"         width="500"></div></li>
    <li><img src="start_ files\img2.jpg" high="250" width="325"></li>
    <li><img src="start_ files\img3.jpg" high="250" width="325"></li>
    <li><img src="start_ files\img4.jpg" high="250" width="325"></li>
    </ol>

.pic {
    opacity: 0.3;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 250px
    margin-right: 250px
    align: center
}
```

Что нужно написать или исправить, чтобы картинка стояла в центре и границы были только вокруг картинки, а не пустого места?

[image]

Comment: html код добавьте

Comment: Нужно показать html, имеющейся информации в вопросе недостаточно

Comment: К предложенным ниже ответам могу добавить. high="250" - такого свойства нет. Есть height. Старайтесь никогда не "захардкоживать" размеры элементов в html, хотя бы в css их выносите.

Answer (score 2):

*Если я правильно понимаю задачу.*

**Например так inline-block:**

```css
.pic {
    opacity: 0.3;
    
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://i-di.org/images/yroki/jivotnie/zveri/bears/cartoon_polar_bear_cub_st5.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

**Или так margin:**

```css
.pic {
    opacity: 0.3;
    
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://i-di.org/images/yroki/jivotnie/zveri/bears/cartoon_polar_bear_cub_st5.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

**Еще вот так flex:**

```css
.pic {
    opacity: 0.3;
    
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

img {border: 3px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://i-di.org/images/yroki/jivotnie/zveri/bears/cartoon_polar_bear_cub_st5.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

**P.S: Конкретно для списка еще так:**

```css
.pic {
    opacity: 0.3;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><div  class="pic"><img src="http://i-di.org/images/yroki/jivotnie/zveri/bears/cartoon_polar_bear_cub_st5.gif" height="325"  width="500"></div></li>
    <li><img src="http://i-di.org/images/yroki/jivotnie/zveri/bears/cartoon_polar_bear_cub_st5.gif" hight="250" width="325"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i-di.org/images/yroki/jivotnie/zveri/bears/cartoon_polar_bear_cub_st5.gif" hight="250" width="325"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i-di.org/images/yroki/jivotnie/zveri/bears/cartoon_polar_bear_cub_st5.gif" hight="250" width="325"></li>
    </ol>
```

....

Answer (score 0):

Задайте нужный размер не изображению, а блоку в котором находится изображение. По умолчанию ширина блока стоит 100% ширины экрана, вот у вас и рамка такая большая

```css
.pic {
  height: 250px;
  width: 325px;
  opacity: 0.3;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 15px;
      }
.pic img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  }

.pic:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://wildwildworld.net.ua/sites/default/files/images/belyj-medved3.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Высоту то зачем? убрать ее надо и с картинки и из контейнера; И что за маргины фиксированные? `margin: 0 auto` c `display: inline-block`; `align` такого аттрибута вообще не существует.

Comment: С высотой не согласен, а в остальном не обратил внимания, просто скопировал стили автора. Про `margin: 0 auto` c `display: inline-block` автору не нужно чтобы картинка была в центре рамки, а наоборот чтобы рамка была на равном расстоянии от картинки. По крайней мере я так понял вопрос.

Comment: так margin на рамку для этого и надо ставить (на контейнер); вы считаете что искажение пропорция картинки это нормально? фиксированной должна быть либо высота либо ширина.

Comment: нет я не считаю что искажение это нормально, но в вопросе высота и ширина изображений фиксирована, если автор посчитает нужным он изменит ее под свои нужды. По `margin` цытирую автора вопроса "чтобы картинка стояла в центре и границы были только вокруг картинки, а не пустого места". Если бы он писал что нужно картинку сделать по центру страницы тогда бы и задавался `margin: 0 auto` для контейнера.